How do I catch/handle a ChunkLoadError from webpack?
I am using Angular 15 and the module federation plugin to load a remote app into our application. I am having issues trying to just catch a ChunkLoadError when webpack fails to load a chunk. I created a global ErrorHandler and regardless it does not catch any ChunkLoadErrors from webpack. I can simply write throw(Error) in the code and that will trigger my errorhandler. Is ChunkLoadError different from a regular JS error?
I've tried overwriting the webpack_load_chunk method to have a try catch and the catch does not execute even when I get the error.
